# http.get with params send word query

Tags: angularjs

This is my first question, excuse my english.

I'm working with angular and I'm using http.post for all (get and post info).  And how this is wrong, I'd start to use http.get for request the record from Database.

I'm using this:

```
$http.get("empresa.php",{params:{id:-1,action:"get"}})
```

I expect receive something like this:

```
empresa.php?id=-1&action=get
```

But not work, because send this:

```
empresa.php?query=%7B%22id%22:-1,%22action%22:%22get%22%7D
```

Could you help me?

**query** is not so I'expect to be.

I'm using Angularjs 1.5.8

**EDITION**
Te factory is this:

```
app.factory("Data", ['$http',
    function($http, ) { // This service connects to our REST API

        var serviceBase = 'service/';

        var obj = {};

        obj.get = function(q,p) {
            console.log(p);
            return $http.get(serviceBase + q + ".php",{params:p}).then(function (results) {
                return results.data;
            });
        };
        obj.post = function(q, object) {
            return $http.post(serviceBase + q + ".php", object).then(function(results) {
                return results.data;
            });
        };
        obj.put = function(q, object) {
            return $http.put(serviceBase + q + ".php", object).then(function(results) {
                return results.data;
            });
        };
        obj.delete = function(q) {
            return $http.delete(serviceBase + q + ".php").then(function(results) {
                return results.data;
            });
        };

        return obj;
    }
]);
```

for POST work fine, but for GET doesn't work :(

**New Edit**

[Here you can see how is that I have the code, how use and the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy1Oj.png)

## Edit - Finalized

At the end, I resolved using **$httpParamSerializer** to serialize the json object and put it directly on call to **empresa.php**

Thanks to all for the help!!!

Comment: So you want to know how to send the get query without characters being converted to their percent-encodings?

Comment: Yes, that is so I want. @ncke

Answer (score 1):

Use `$httpParamSerializer` to build the url query for you.

```
var params = {id:-1,action:"get"};
var query = $httpParamSerializer(params);
$http.get("empresa.php?" + query);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.  The http.get is in a factory for use it in all the project and I don't know how to use $httpParamSerializer

Comment: @DanielB, we can help if you can put the code you have in the factory

Answer (score 0):

Try not using the $http.get shortcut method.

```
$http({
    url: "empresa.php", 
    method: "GET",
    params: {id:-1, action:"get"}
});
```

Or else you can create the url yourself.

```
$http.get('empresa.php?id=' + -1 + '&action=' + 'get');
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, change the shorcut way for the large, but still not working.  At the end I used put "manual" the parameters in the query string and work.

Comment: But I don't know why in other project work fine.  It's the same server, the call to http.get is in a factory (in both projects).